# How do I deal with 'poison pill' messages when using Google Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

When using Amazon's SQS for example, I can define a dead letter queue (DLQ) where any message that has failed to be deleted (ack'd) after X retries will be routed to for separate processing.. but it Google Cloud Platform I don't see any mention of this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of AWS Dead Letter Queue in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568906/what-is-the-equivalent-of-aws-dead-letter-queue-in-google-cloud-platform)

Comment: Question is on poison-letters but details are on dead-letters and these are by no means the same thing.  A poison message has no hope of being successfully processed without a code change somewhere in the pipeline.  A dead-letter is one that can be successfully processed following a delay, due to a temporary outage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub does not currently have any automatic dead letter queues. If you are worried about "poison pill" messages, you will have to support this in some capacity yourself by persistently keeping a map from the message ID to the number of times the message has been delivered. You would update this map in your subscriber before reading the data in the message. Once acknowledged, you remove from the map. If the count exceeds some threshold, you could publish it to a separate Cloud Pub/Sub topic that you use to keep track of such messages and then ack the message.

Comment: Just a bit over a 1.5 years since the original response and I was curious whether there are any updated best practices in this area. Does pub/sub offer any primitives for error handling/routing? Or does this logic need to be baked into the subscribe to "re-publish" any nacked messages?

Comment: It is something being considered, but this answer still is correct.

Comment: @Tkwon123 Please see my answer to the question, it's finally possible ;)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks @grzechoo - adding a link to your comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568906/what-is-the-equivalent-of-aws-dead-letter-queue-in-google-cloud-platform/60316820#60316820 and the updated documentation for reference https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create#--max-delivery-attempts

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Pub/Sub now supports [Dead Letter Queues](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics) that can be used to handle poison pill messages.